# Parsing Node Command Line Arguments

Tags: json, node.js, command-line-arguments

I am learning how to use node.js, but am having trouble parsing command-line arguments. The following line:

```
node test.js --input=in.txt
```

Gives a parsing error when the code reaches this command:

```
var fileName = JSONparse.(process.argv[2]);
```

Results in the error:

```
 undefined
--input=in.txt 

Syntax error: Unexpected number
```

What I am trying to do is create an optional variable for the input file. If it is not specified in the command-line, it should resolve to 'a.txt'.

I have not found an easy way of creating default parameters, or use identifiers such as '--input=' to not have to worry about the order in which arguments are passed (I know it does not matter in this case with one argument).

Comment: Incidentally, `Syntax error` is because the JS syntax is bad. There is no `JSONparse`, and even if there was, `JSONparse.(` doesn't make sense; `.` is to access a member, so you need an identifier after `.`; `(` doesn't work.

Perhaps you meant `JSON.parse(process.argv[2])`, but that doesn't make sense either since the string is not JSON.

Comment: You are right @Jacob, I did mean JSON.parse. However:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) is a framework I made for building interactive CLIs in Node. As part of this, it has a built-in API for easy command parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse something, it should be a stringified JSON object or parsing results in error.
It is important to know that all the command line arguments in node js are strings

```
let fileName = 'a.txt'

process.argv.slice(2).forEach((arg) => {
  if(arg.indexOf('--input') !== -1){
    if(arg.indexOf('=') !== -1){
      fileName = arg.split("=")[1].trim()
    } else {
      console.log('Error in providing command line argument')
    }
  }
})

console.log("File Name is ",fileName)
```

for `node index` output will be

> File Name is a.txt

for `node index --input=hello.txt`, the output will be

> File Name is hello.txt

Answer (score 0):

Best option: use an existing command line parser. The [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module works pretty well.

If you want to roll your own, here's the approach I'd take. First, create an object with all your defaults:

```
var opts = { 
  inputStream: process.stdin,
  verbose: false
};
```

...then just loop through the args, replacing the options as you go. If an option wasn't present, then the defaults will be used:

```
for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
  var arg = process.argv[i];
  var keyValue = arg.split('=');  
  var key = keyValue[0], value = keyValue[1];
  if (key === '--input' || key === '-i') {
      opts.inputStream = fs.createReadStream(value);
  }
  if (key === '---verbose' || key === '-v')  {
      opts.verbose = true;
  }
  // etc.
}
```